# Bgnr: Creating a list to subsite

Tags: list, site-collection, site

I'm trying to create a list on/to my subsite.  Am I doing this correct?

Can a list be created on a subsite?

If not, where do I create my list. I've been given privileges only to my team subsite.

Answer (score 1):

You can create List in SharePoint subsites too.

try this code:

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("your sitecollection URL"))
{
    oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb("your subsite URL"))
    {
        oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        oSPWeb.Lists.Add("Your List Name", "Description", SPListTemplateType.Links);

        oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }

    oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
```

Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have correct permissions then you can create list on subsite.

Their is no such restrictions,  where should you create lists...you can create at root level or subsite level.